# "this" dentro de arrow function usada como método de um objeto não aponta para o objeto

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, this

O `this` do `carro2` não deveria apontar para o contexto no qual ele foi criado (no caso dentro de `carro2`)?

Segue um exemplo com o `this` de `function` normal e outro com *arrow function*:

```js
    const carro = {
        modelo: 'Fiesta',
        fabricante: 'Ford',
        nomeCompleto: function(){ 
            return `${this.fabricante} ${this.modelo}`
        } } 

        console.log(carro.nomeCompleto()) // Imprime normalmente
    
    
    const carro2 = {
        modelo: 'Fiesta',
        fabricante: 'Ford',
        nomeCompleto: () => {
            return `${this.fabricante} ${this.modelo}`
        } }
    
    console.log(carro2.nomeCompleto()) // Imprime Undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo [este trecho da documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method):

> *When a function is called as a method of an object, its `this` is set to the object the method is called on.*

Em tradução livre:

> Quando uma função é chamada como um método de um objeto, o `this` desta é setado para o objeto no qual o método é chamado.

Por isso que o primeiro caso funciona, pois dentro da função `nomeCompleto`, o `this` refere-se ao objeto `carro`:

```js
const carro = {
    modelo: 'Fiesta',
    fabricante: 'Ford',
    nomeCompleto: function () {
        console.log(this === carro); // true
        return `${this.fabricante} ${this.modelo}`;
    }
};

console.log(carro.nomeCompleto()); // Ford Fiesta
```

---

Já para o segundo caso, [a documentação sobre *arrow functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) diz claramente que elas não são adequadas para serem usadas como métodos ("*Arrow function expressions are ill suited as methods*"), justamente por não setarem o `this` para o objeto no qual elas estão, e [neste trecho](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Arrow_functions_used_as_methods) há um exemplo explicando que o `this` não é setado para o objeto.

Para entendermos melhor, considere o objeto abaixo:

```js
const obj = {
    valor: this
}

console.log(obj.valor == globalThis); // true
```

Dentro do objeto `obj`, o `this` é o objeto global. E como uma *arrow function* não tem o seu próprio `this` e usa o `this` do escopo no qual ela está, então uma *arrow function* dentro deste objeto usará o objeto global como `this`. E é isso que acontece no segundo caso:

```js
const carro2 = { // não cria um novo escopo, this é o objeto global
    modelo: 'Fiesta',
    fabricante: 'Ford',
    nomeCompleto: () => { // aqui o this é o objeto global
        console.log(this == globalThis); // true
        return `${this.fabricante} ${this.modelo}`;
    }
};

console.log(carro2.nomeCompleto()); // undefined
```

Ou seja, você está tentando acessar as propriedades `fabricante` e `modelo` do objeto global, e como elas não foram definidas, o resultado é `undefined`.